# ldapmodify: Trying to add records from file

Tags: openldap

So I'm trying to add records from an ldif file.  What's weird is that with one file that I generated, the command works fine.  When I try to run it with a different file (generated the same way), it looks like it runs, but returns me to the cli prompt immediately.  No error, no add text indicating it worked.  I've looked at the files, and they basically look identical.

With the file that works, if I remove all the records except one, you would expect it to still work.  But it doesn't.  If I copy all the records from the "good" file to the "bad" file, it doesn't work.

```
ldapmodify.exe -a -x -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=..." -w <password>; -h <hostname> -f test-OUT_2.ldif -v -n
```

I'm not sure what is going on, but does anyone have any troubleshooting advice in regards to ldapmodify and this ldif file?

Here's a sample entry.  Each entry separated by a blank line.

```
dn: cn=J811280798,ou=Active,dc=domain,dc=com
changetype:  add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: cojudExtended
displayName: doe, john
cn: doe, john
givenName: john
cn: J811280798
sn: doe
mail: john.doe@domain.com
userPassword:  {SSHA}86uhsAvPgBXm8yEmhrnCUiE/tyObn+NZ
uid: bap08jd
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `use Encode qw(encode_utf8);` to encode my output to UTF-8 and it's working like it should.